# Plotting with two different labels in X-axis in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a dataframe like this -

[image: 1]

I want to plot for every date `tmax` & `tmin` value on y axis.
How can I do this using matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df['Data_Value'].unstack().plot()
```

Or with [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
df['Data_Value'].unstack().plot.bar()
```